Phantom Wallet "Word Mispelled"
Curious if anyone understood why Phantom keeps saying "Wrong Spelling" when I try to write "Immerse" in my seed?
Literally the only way to spell that word.

You can find all the available words here:
https://www.bitcoinsafety.com/blogs/bitcoin/seed-phrase-list
The word you are looking for is probably immense instead of immerse
